# Community for open source / online collaboration manner

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I wonder if there a StackExchange community for open-source manner questions, like

> how to politely ask someone who sent a pull request to fix his own bugs

(It's a bit silly, but I do think it's a legit question for some people.)

The closest one I've found is [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), but according to their help center [article](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it's more focused on actual workplaces involved with employment, not the collaboration between online strangers.

Comment: Maybe SE Software Engineering is an appropriate site. At least they have [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go) at their Meta site.

Comment: I think Interpersonal Skills is worth checking out but they might be scoped similar like TWP. For the specific question I would probably say: *Hey dude, fix your own crap* but YMMV on the response ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You're probably looking for [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/).**

*(But check their on-topic rules before posting.)*

In future, you can find [a full site list at stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites).